# Github pages - project site showing up as 404

Tags: html, github, dns, web-hosting, github-pages

I have recently started using github pages to host my personal website. I bought a domain from namecheap and applied it to the settings, so I can now access my website with my domain name and with the basic 'username.github.io'.

That works perfectly fine.

Afterwards, I created another repository - a project site - and committed/pushed content to it (which is of another website that I previously created). I made sure the main html file is index.html (with a lower case I) and that the branch connects to that of the master.

However, when I try and access this repository, I get a 404 error (aka, file not found error).

E.g.

username.github.io/mynewprojectsite will return a 404 error, and
www.mydomain.ca/mynewprojectsite will also return a 404 error.

I've tried emailing github customer service but had no luck in receiving a reply yet.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind posting the link to the GitHub pages repo in question?

Comment: Nevermind guys, I got it all figured out. Make sure your files are all in lower case - even the html part. For example, 'index.HTML' - you will not be able to view the project site unless you include the index.HTML at the end. Make sure it is 'index.html'.

Comment: Same problem, but index.html is lower case...